# Web Audio API - Why is my audio processing callback not receiving playbackTime?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-audio-api

I'm trying to implement a custom Web Audio API node, by way of the [ScriptProcessorNode](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#ScriptProcessorNode-section) interface. I've got most of it working, but for some reason the [event](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioProcessingEvent-section) passed to `onaudioprocess` doesn't define the `playbackTime` property. Why is this?

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var proc = context.createScriptProcessor(16384, 0, 2);

proc.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
    if (!event.playbackTime) {
        console.log("No playback time");
    }

    proc.disconnect(0);
};

proc.connect(context.destination);
```

What happens is that `proc.onaudioprocess` gets called by the Web Audio API, but `event.playbackTime` is undefined. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybGyJ/1/) for a demonstration of the problem ("No playback time" should be printed to the console).

I've tested so far with Chromium 32.0.1700.107 on Linux and Chrome 33.0.1750.117 on Windows.

Comment: The browser you're using may be relevant here. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105518

Comment: @Brad Tested with Chromium/Chrome. That bug's pretty old, is it still not implemented?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.  The core Chromium team doesn't really seem to care much about Web Audio.  I've ran into many issues (for example https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82795), and the team's comments on bugs often imply that they shrug it off and will deal with it some other time.  To be fair, the spec is still draft, so that might have something to do with their indifference.  Also, Chrome/Chromium seems to support Web Audio better than any other at the moment.  This is the state of things with Web Audio.  It will be a few more years before this is fully standardized.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, feel free to write this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a webkit bug which you may be running into.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105518

> As per W3C WebAudio Spec AudioProcessingEvent Interface should have parameters like below:

```
interface AudioProcessingEvent : Event {

        JavaScriptAudioNode node;
        readonly attribute float playbackTime;
        readonly attribute AudioBuffer inputBuffer;
        readonly attribute AudioBuffer outputBuffer; 

    }
```

> W3C Spec link: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webaudio-20120802/
>
> The parameter "playbackTime" is not present in latest WebKit-137862. Also if required, necessary calculations to update the playbackTime parameter need to be implemented in AudioProcessingEvent.
>
> Current Implementation AudioProcessingEvent.idl:

```
[
    Conditional=WEB_AUDIO,
    JSGenerateToJSObject
] interface AudioProcessingEvent : Event {
    readonly attribute AudioBuffer inputBuffer;
    readonly attribute AudioBuffer outputBuffer; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for investigating on this matter!

Answer (score 2):

Note that is the Webkit bug (i.e. the Safari one) - the Blink (Chrome) bug is at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332782.

Obviously, I wouldn't characterize it as "core Chromium team doesn't care much about Web Audio" - there are just some issues that haven't sorted up to the top of the stack, and having lost Chris Rogers from the team last year was kind of a hit to our productivity.  :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the situation re. Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: @cwilso Thanks for the link. I want to clarify my comment for you, to ensure you don't take it personally. There are absolutely critical bugs that require ugly hacks to get well-documented features of Web Audio to work properly. I don't blame the developers for this at all.  With the spec always changing, and a huge amount of debate surrounding every aspect of it, I can see why the priority on these issues is low.  I'm grateful that we have what we have, but expectation of quality must certainly be lowered for Web Audio since much of it does not work properly.  It is experimental, after all.

Comment: I don't think it's experimental - it's not rock-solid across browsers yet, because we've only had a second implementation out there for a few short months.  But that said - file bugs, on both Chrome and FF.